# Searching an array list for most common String

Tags: java

I was wondering how I could search an ArrayList of Strings to find the most commonly occurring 'destination' in an 'Itinerary' object I've created (which contains a list of different destinations.)

So far I have:

```
public static String commonName(ArrayList<Itinerary> itinerary){

    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String>itr2 = names.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){ 

        Itinerary temp = itr.next();  

        if(temp.iterator().hasNext()){ //if its has destinations

                // Destination object in itinerary object 
                Destination temp2 = temp.iterator().next(); 
                String name = temp2.getDestination().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");

                if(names.contains(name)){
                    count = count + 1;
                    //do something with counting the occurence of string name here
                }
```

I'm having problems making an algorithm to search the array for the most commonly occurring string, or strings if there is a tie; and then displaying the number of the 'Itinerary object' (the parameter value) the string is found in. Any help would be great, thank you!!

Comment: Adding a comment to each line describing in words exactly what the Java code says is not useful, as a matter of fact it's distracting and ugly.

Comment: To add to Paul's argument it becomes a disaster when you change the code but do not update the comment to reflect the changes

Answer (score 8):

I would make a `HashMap<String,Integer>`.  Then I would go through each itinerary, and if the destination wans't in the Map I would create an entry with put(destination, 1), otherwise I would increment the count that was there with put(destination, get(destination)+1).  Afterwards I'd go through the Map entries and look for the one with the highest count.

Comment: It's probably not the most efficient (based on CPU cycles), but it's definitely the first to mind as the least amount of code that gets the job done.  +1.

Comment: you could skip the last step (running through the map entries and look for the highest count) if you kept a 'max' value as you incrmented the get(destingation)+1 step. If the new value was larger than any seen yet then store off a pointer to that entry. (I think this is the fastest solution as it is O(n). Certainly faster than sorting which is nLogn )

Comment: My solution is O(N) - you're traversing the list of itineraries once, then you're traversing the list of destinations found once.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using an external jar, you could use HashBag from apache commons to do this easily.

```
public static String commonName(ArrayList<Itinerary> itinerary){

int count = 0;
int total = 0;
Bag names = new HashBag();

while(itr.hasNext()){ //while array of Itinerary object has next
    Itinerary temp = itr.next();  //temp = 1st itineray object
    if(temp.iterator().hasNext()){ //if its has destinations
            Destination temp2 = temp.iterator().next(); //n Destination object in itinerary object 
            String name = temp2.getDestination().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
            names.add(name, 1);
    }
}
```

And then later you can call names.getCount("destination1") to get the number of occurrences of destination1

See http://commons.apache.org/collections/userguide.html#Bags

Comment: Thank you all for the extremely quick and helpful answers! I just started learning Java and although I haven't used HashBag before Ill be sure to look it up in the java API! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try the group feature of the [lambdaj](https://github.com/mariofusco/lambdaj) library. To solve your problem you could group the Itenarary objects on the destination property and then find the group with the biggest size as in the following example:

```
Group<Sale> group = selectMax(group(itineraries, 
    by(on(Itenarary.class).getDestination())).subgroups(), on(Group.class).getSize());
```

Answer (score 0):

[In statistics, this is called the "mode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)). A vanilla Java 8 solution looks like this:

```
itinerary
      .stream()
      .flatMap(i -> StreamSupport.stream(
          Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(i.iterator(), 0)
      ))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
          s -> s.getDestination().toLowerCase().replace(" ", ""), 
          Collectors.counting()
      ))
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

[jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) is a library that supports [`mode()`](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/Collectable.html#mode--) on streams. The following program:

```
System.out.println(
    Seq.seq(itinerary)
       .flatMap(i -> Seq.seq(i.iterator()))
       .map(s -> s.getDestination().toLowerCase().replace(" ", ""))
       .mode()
);
```

(disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ)